# Why the acc of DNN is less than 1%

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

Im a new in deeplearning. I have a X with 34 dimension, which are some stock technical indicator data. And Y is label, which is binary(1,-1) represent the stock is uptrend or downtrend.Here is my code.

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('data/data_week.csv')
data.dropna(inplace=True)
x = data.loc[:, 'bbands_upperband':'turn_std_5']
y = data['label']

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_dim=34))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=2, batch_size=200)



 231200/1041021 [=====>........................] - ETA: 59s - loss: 0.7098 - acc: 0.0086
 232000/1041021 [=====>........................] - ETA: 59s - loss: 0.7087 - acc: 0.0086
```

However, the accuracy is less than 1%. I think this must has something wrong.
If you know please tell me and thank you very much!

Comment: Reasons for your problem can be many things. First of all I recommend you to change the target variable as 1, 0 and train the model with sigmoid activation function at the output layer. After that remove some layers are reduce the neurons in the layers.

Comment: change to sigmoid works!!! cool! thank you!!

Comment: Happy to hear it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a binary classification model you should use sigmoid activation function in your last dense layer

```python
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

also, your classes must be (0,1) not (-1,1)